# Close gaps between some polygons, which are adjacent in reality

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, gap

I have tens of thousands of polygons (farmer plots) which have been measured while on the fields. This has caused plenty of gaps between some polygons, which is not the reality. I would need to close these gaps, see the red marks (arrows and circles) in the screen shot attached.

However, I can't seem to find a good approach to only adjust the relevant polygons. I have mainly found solutions for when the polygons are supposed to cover an entire area, but this is not the case. I have tried the convex hull function but it is changing the shape of all the polygons, which I don't want.  Thus, I don't think that buffer and dissolve is an option. I also need to save the information kept in the attribute table. I only want the boundaries to meet, not overlap as I want to avoid double counting of some areas in my further analysis (yes, as also in the picture some plots overlap, which I need to go about, but that's another question).

[image]

Comment: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/analysis/QgsInternalGeometrySnapper.html

This might be of some assistance.

Comment: Thanks @whjd . But I need to do some python programming then, right? Haven't done before and not used to either QGIS or programming... Is that the only way, do you know?

Comment: Small gaps and errors could be addressed by using the QGIS snap geometries to layer tool or the GRASS v.clean tool.  That's simple.  Here's some clumsier ideas. Larger gaps might be addressed by creating a "background" polygon which is used in symmetrical difference to create "fill" polys to add to your layer and then use the Eliminate tool to add them to abutting polys.  You might even look at converting to rasters, then applying some raster tools like EuclideanAllocation (the Whitebox toolbox for QGIS has it), and then converting the results back to polygons.